# choosing healthy control from a very large dataset

Tags: r, t-test, statistical-test

I would like to run a  unpaired t-test. I have a very large dataset of 500,000 participants and only 21 participants have a disease. how can I choose my healthy control from this large dataset?

any thoughts would help.
I am using R for analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a random sample of the same size as your control sample, that is, a random sample of size 21. The `sample` function will help you. Also, you may want to replicate the same ratio of men to women. For example, if there are 10 men and 11 women, then you would have to sample two patients depending on their gender.

In short, it would be best to use sample to replicate the characteristics of your 21 patients randomly from the large sample of healthy patients.

Comment: will sample function be a good representation for all the data ? is it going to change every time I run the script or fixed

Comment: you have to use `set.seed()` before running `sample()` to make reproducible

Comment: perfect.. I have seen set.seed(123) and set.seed(12345678) can you tell based on what I choose the values of set.seed? thanks a lot

Comment: The `set.seed()` function sets the starting number used to generate a sequence of random numbers – it ensures that you get the same result if you start with that same seed each time you run the same process. For example, if I use the `sample()` function immediately after setting a seed, I will always get the same sample. So putting a number 123 in `set.seed(123)` ensures that the random process is the same, the number itself does not matter.

Comment: @k-peltzer K. Peltzer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908737/r-bootstrapping-with-control-for-age-and-gender can you please have a look at this